# Remove more than 1 select option using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, select

I have 3 columns of HTML selection fields which need to load otions dependent on the previous selection fields.

Selection in column 2 values will be dependant on selected value in column 1 selection.  I have this raw JavaScript below which add 2 selection options to a an HTML select filed and then removes 2 based on the select value in selection 1.

My problem is that the part that removes the 2 selection field options is not removing both options but instead removes 1 of them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/croh2nj8/3/

I realize some of this uses jQuery but the goal is to use raw JS without jQuery for this part in question....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#action").change(function() {

    var el = $(this) ;
    var selectAttributeEl = document.getElementById('action-attribute');

    if(el.val() === "form" ) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = 'Name';
        var option2 = document.createElement('option');
        option2.text = 'ActionURL';
        selectAttributeEl.add(option);
        selectAttributeEl.add(option2);

    }else if(el.val() === "link" ) {
        for (var i=0; i<selectAttributeEl.length; i++){
          if (selectAttributeEl.options[i].value == 'Name'){
             selectAttributeEl.remove(i);
          }else if(selectAttributeEl.options[i].value == 'ActionURL'){
             selectAttributeEl.remove(i);
          }
        }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: you're getting the issue because in your `for` loop, when you come across an element you delete it, which removes the node from the node list of `options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated, you're getting the issue, very simply, because the for loop is started from index `0` and working your way up. When you remove an element, you remove it from the `NodeList` of `options`. Easiest way I know of is to start from the end of the node list and work your way to node number 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#action").change(function() {

    var el = $(this);

    if (el.val() === "form") {
      //$("#action-attribute").append('   <option value="Name">Name</option>');
      //$("#action-attribute").append('   <option value="ActionURL">ActionURL</option>');
      var x = document.getElementById('action-attribute');
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = 'Name';
      var option2 = document.createElement('option');
      option2.text = 'ActionURL';
      x.add(option);
      x.add(option2);

    } else if (el.val() === "link") {
      //$("#action-attribute option:last-child").remove() ; 
      var selectobject = document.getElementById("action-attribute");
      var remove_array = ['Name', 'ActionURL'];
      for (var i = selectobject.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (remove_array.indexOf(selectobject.options[i].value) != -1) {
          selectobject.removeChild(selectobject.options[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When :
<select id="action" name="action">
  <option value="link">Link Clicked</option>
  <option value="form">Form Submitted</option>
</select>

with:

<select id="action-attribute" name="action-attribute">
  <option>ID</option>
  <option>Class</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just a quick typo I noticed, should be `i>=0` since you want to check the first option as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `for` loop where you loop through the `selectobject.options`. When the first `if` condition is true, you mutate `selectobject.options` by removing the `Name` option. On the next iteration of the loop `selectobject.options[i]` now returns `undefined`.

Let's walk through the `for` loop to demonstrate:

1. `i` is 0, corresponding to option `ID`, nothing happens.
2. `i` is 1, corresponding to option `Class`, nothing happens.
3. `i` is 2, corresponding to option `Name`, the `if` statement is valid and it removes the `Name` option. Now `selectobject.options` has `length` of 3.
4. `i` is 3, which corresponds to `undefined`. That is, `selectobject.options[3]` is `undefined` since the previous iteration of the loop removed an item from `selectobject.options`.

One possible solution, in the `if` and `else` statements you could reset `i` back one, with `i--`. Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/d3ddLe5h/1/). Another option is too loop through `selectobject.options` backwards, as mutating the latter items won't effect the counter as it moves to the former items.

There are other ways to correct this as well, like creating a new `options` array based on the values you want to keep in the options, then loading it the new options into the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

May I propose a different approach? Instead of maintaining the state of the menu by removing elements that shouldn't be there, blow away the menu `option` tags entirely and replace.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
      link: ['ID', 'Class']
    },
    dependentMenu = document.getElementById('action-attribute');

  options.form = options.link.concat(['Name', 'ActionURL']);

  $("#action").change(function() {

    var el = $(this);

    while (dependentMenu.firstChild) {
      dependentMenu.removeChild(dependentMenu.firstChild);
    }

    options[el.val()].forEach(function(value) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = value;
      dependentMenu.add(option);
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When :
<select id="action" name="action">
  <option value="link">Link Clicked</option>
  <option value="form">Form Submitted</option>
</select>

with:

<select id="action-attribute" name="action-attribute">
  <option>ID</option>
  <option>Class</option>
</select>
```